# Why my code didn't work correct in this problem

Tags: c, recursion, dynamic-programming

**the grid travel problem**

she is basically recursion problem and this is it : [grid travel problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBt53YbR9Kk&list=WL&index=1&t=2340s)

and this is my solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int gridtravel(int r, int c) {
    if (r == 1 && c == 1) return 1;
    if (r == 0 || c == 0) return 0;
    return gridtravel(r - 1, c) + gridtravel(r, c - 1); 
}

int main() {
    int r, c;
    scanf("%i%i", &r, &c);
    printf("%i\n", gridtravel(r, c));
}
```

**but** when I want to reduce the time complexity with solution like this I get a incorrect result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int gridtravel(int r, int c, int arr[][c]) {
    if (arr[r][c] != 0) return arr[r][c];
    if (arr[c][r] != 0) return arr[c][r];
    if (r == 1 && c == 1) return 1;
    if (r == 0 || c == 0) return 0;
    arr[r][c] = gridtravel(r - 1, c, arr) + gridtravel(r, c - 1, arr);
    return arr[r][c];
}

int main() {
    int r, c;
    scanf("%i%i", &r, &c);
    int arr[r][c];
    for (int i = 0; i <= r; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= c; ++j) {
            arr[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("%i\n", gridtravel(r, c, arr));
}
```

Comment: Time to drop it into a debugger and find out why.

Comment: The "size" you give when defining the array is the number of elements, not the top index. So an array of `r` elements have indexes from `0` to `r - 1`, inclusive. This all means you go out of bounds of your array, and that leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Note that the type of VLA you are passing *changes* at every recursive call (`int arr[][c]` is different from `int arr[][c - 1]`), while it should be the same.

Comment: `arr[c][r]` cannot be correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some problems:

- Your code has undefined behavior because the initialization loops write beyond the end of the array: `for (int i = 0; i <= r; ++i)` should be `for (int i = 0; i < r; ++i)` and `for (int j = 0; j <= c; ++j)` should be `for (int j = 0; j < c; ++j)`. You could also simplify this as `memset(arr, 0, sizeof(arr))`.
- Furthermore, you must pass the array dimensions separately from the cell coordinates.
- The array must be allocated as a square matrix since you access both `arr[r][c]` and `arr[c][r]`.
- Given how you use the cache array, it should be allocated with one more row and column.
- You should take advantage of the fact that `gridtravel(1,x)` and `gridtravel(x,1)` are both `1` if `x` is greater than `0`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int gridtravel(int r, int c, int n, int arr[][n]) {
    if (arr[r][c] != 0) return arr[r][c];
    if (arr[c][r] != 0) return arr[c][r];
    if (r == 0 || c == 0) return 0;
    if (r == 1 || c == 1) return 1;
    return arr[r][c] = gridtravel(r - 1, c, n, arr) + gridtravel(r, c - 1, n, arr);
}

int main() {
    int r, c;
    if (scanf("%i%i", &r, &c) != 2 || r < 1 || c < 1)
        return 1;
    int n = (r > c) ? r + 1 : c + 1;
    int arr[n][n];
    memset(arr, 0, sizeof arr);
    printf("%i\n", gridtravel(r, c, n, arr));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issues:

- The bounds of the are `c-1` and `r-1`
- you cannot swap index `c` and `r`
- 2D arrays are not so easy to handle.

If you want to use big array malloc can be better than using the stack.

With 2d array you have to give the size as a parameter

Here the code with the modification with the printf to follow the travel

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int gridtravel(int n, int r,int c, int (*arr)[n]){
    printf("travel to %d %d\n", r, c);
    if(arr[r][c]!=0) return arr[r][c];
    if(r==1 && c==1) return 1;
    if(r==0 || c==0) return 0;
    
    arr[r][c] = gridtravel(n, r-1, c, arr)+gridtravel(n, r, c-1, arr);
    return arr[r][c];
}

int main(){
    int r,c;
    scanf("%i%i",&r,&c);
    int (*arr)[c] = malloc(sizeof(int[r][c]));
    memset(arr, 0, r*c*sizeof(int));
    printf("%i\n",gridtravel(c, r - 1, c - 1, arr));
    free(arr);
}
```